# Gerrit settings how to notify author when a change has merge conflict by default

Tags: configuration, gerrit

For either All Projects or for a specific project, I can't find a way to notify the author of an open change submitted to Gerrit that this change has now a merge conflict.

I looked into the documentation in [Project owner guide, Email Notifications](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-project-owner.html#notifications) and [Notifications, Project level settings](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-notify.html#project).

This would be useful if, by default, a project owner wants his team of developers to have these notifications by default, not to all persons in the team, but, only to the author of the open change which now has a merge conflict.

According to the documentation a specific user may add this specific email notification globally in Settings > Watched Projects with:

- Repo: All-projects
- Search expression: owner:self status:open -is:mergeable
- Select "Changes".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using watched projects. You'll need to execute a script periodically to search for this information in Gerrit using REST.

**Step 1**

Find the open changes with merge conflicts.

The following command will search for all open changes, not WIP, not private and not mergeable, and return their change number and the change owner id:

```
curl -s --request GET --user USER:PASS https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/?q=status:open+AND+-is:wip+AND+-is:private+AND+-is:mergeable | sed 1d | jq --raw-output '.[] | [._number, .owner._account_id | tostring] | join(" ")'
```

**Step 2**

Find the users e-mails.

The following command will search for the change owner id and return his/her e-mail:

```
curl -s --request GET --user USER:PASS https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/accounts/CHANGE-OWNER-ID | sed 1d | jq --raw-output .email
```

**Step 3**

Send the e-mail notifications.